# Is it possible to more nicely format the help for a function?

Tags: emacs

When I use `describe-function`, I get the documentation text displayed in a Help buffer.

If the doc is long enough, it will wrap in the buffer, but it doesn't wrap nicely.  like this:

[image]

I can make the docstring use 72-character lines, but that supposes that the window will be 80 characters, which is not always the case.

Is it possible to get `describe-function` to emit documentation in a more nicely formatted way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try enabling `global-visual-line-mode` to get nice text wrapping in all your buffers.  It works in code and help buffers, but doesn't mess up your line numbering!  Of all the line wrapping modes for emacs, I find it to be the best.  If you don't want to use it globally, simply try `M-x visual-line-mode`.

Answer (score 0):

No, please do *not* "try enabling global-visual-line-mode" as your solution for this.

Just try adopting the Emacs conventions for doc strings.  See the Elisp manual, node `Documentation Tips` (aka "Tips for Documentation Strings").

In general, doc strings should not have lines wider than 60 chars.

Remember that there are multiple places where Emacs uses doc strings, including for `apropos`.  Emacs expects doc strings to follow the documented conventions, for best results.